# Probability distribution for a geometric distribution don't add up to 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say I'm rolling 2 dies, numbered 1 to 10.
A successful outcome is considered rolling a multiple of 4.
Therefore, probability of success $=0.25$ and prob of failure $=0.75$.
This is an example of a geometric distribution.
I can roll a maximum of 6 times.
I made the prob distribution chart to represent all the different possibilities, but my values don't add up to $1$.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

\begin{align}
\text{Roll} &\text{ Number}  & &\text{Probability} &&\\  
X &= 1 && (0.75)ˆ0(0.25) && 0.25 \\
X &= 2 && (0.75)ˆ1(0.25) && 0.1875 \\
X &= 3 && (0.75)ˆ2(0.25) && 0.140625 \\
X &= 4 && (0.75)ˆ3(0.25) && 0.10546875 \\
X &= 5 && (0.75)ˆ4(0.25) && 0.079101562 \\
X &= 6 && (0.75)ˆ5(0.25) && 0.059326171
\end{align}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that your error stems from believing that each outcome, $1 \rightarrow 20$ is equally likely.  But that is not the case.  Consider how many ways you can get the outcome of $10$ and of $2$, to take just one example comparison.

Comment: I don't understand.I drew up a table listing all the different outcomes I could get using the 2 dies.I had 25 out of a 100 outcomes that were multiples of 4.Isn't that my probability of success?

Comment: Did you consider the case of $6$ failures  ? If you add $0.75^6$ to your sum, you get $1$ within your accuracy.

Comment: Ohh.I get it now.Thankyou for pointing that out.Should I frame the question a bit differently?Are all the required variables clearly defined?

Comment: Yes, please edit the question. Denote $X$=number of trials needed to get a success. And $X>6$ means that you got $6$ failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the random variable $X$ has not been precisely defined, we will supply a (speculative) definition.

The game consists of rolling the two dice repeatedly. We stop when we roll a sum divisible by $4$ or when the total number of rolls reaches $6$. Let $X$ be the number of rolls.  It is indeed true that the probability of getting a sum divisible by $4$ on a roll of the two dice (probability of a success) is $0.25$.

For $k=1$ to $5$, the probability that $X=k$ is given by the familiar geometric distribution. Thus $\Pr(X=k)=(0.75)^{k-1}(0.25)$.

But $k=6$ is special. We have $k=6$ precisely if there have been $5$ failures in a row. Thus $\Pr(X=6)=(0.75)^5$.

**Remark:** Or else we could say that $X=6$ can happen in two ways: (i) our first sum divisible by $4$ occurs on the $6$th roll or (ii) the $6$th roll results in failure. Then we get $\Pr(X=6)=(0.75)^5(0.25)+(0.75)^6$. That turns out to be the $(0.75)^5$ that we obtained in a simpler way in the answer above.

Comment: That seems to give me the correct answer.Could you please explain why I would do (0.75)^5 for X==6?

Comment: I have added a remark that does $\Pr(X=6)$ in a more complicated way. But for the simple way, recall that if we did $6$ rolls we are forced to stop. So if we have had $5$ failures in a row, we are allowed one more roll, but that's all. Thus we end up doing $6$ rolls precisely if we have not had a success on the first $5$ trials. That probability is $(0.75)^5$.